# Pandas Dataframe with Groupby from DF1 and Sum from other df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got these two dataframes:

df1:

```
    A      |  B   | C
2023-10-31 | foo  | bar
2023-11-30 | foo  | bar
2023-12-31 | foo  | bar
...
```

df2:

```
    D      | E   | F
2023-10-31 | 23  | bar
2023-10-31 | 25  | bar
2023-10-31 | 34  | bar
...
```

And I would like to `groupby()` column `A` and sum over column `E`.
The problem is that there are different amounts of dates in both dataframes (there is one less in `df2`)

I tried:

```py
df1["D"] = df2.groupby(["D"]).agg({"E": sum}).values
```

Which leads to the:

> ValueError: Length of values does match length of index

My only other idea is to use `iterrows()` with `iloc`

Comment: In `df1`, set index to A first. Then run your code. Don't call it with `values`. The reason why you're getting this issue is because the two assignment variables have different lengths. You can align also on labels, which is what setting A as index and aligning on D would do.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to align the output of the groupby operation on A:

```
df1['D'] = df1['A'].map(df2.groupby(['D'])['E'].sum())
```

Output:

```
            A    B    C     D
0  2023-10-31  foo  bar  82.0
1  2023-11-30  foo  bar   NaN
2  2023-12-31  foo  bar   NaN
```

If you have a DataFrame as output, you can merge:

```
out = df1.merge(df2.groupby(['D']).agg({'E': 'sum'}), left_on='A', right_index=True, how='left')
```

Output:

```
            A    B    C     E
0  2023-10-31  foo  bar  82.0
1  2023-11-30  foo  bar   NaN
2  2023-12-31  foo  bar   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets to Pandas' indexing. There are two (relevant) ways to assign columns in Pandas. You can align on the length of the rows element-by-element or you can align on the index labels. Consider the following data frame.

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [7, 8, 9]}).set_index('A')
```

You can add a column by assigning a list, but this only works if you have the same lengths. This seems to be the issue you're having right now.

```
>>> df['C'] = [4, 5, 6]
   B  C
A      
1  7  4
2  8  5
3  9  6

>>> df['C'] = [4, 5, 6, 7]
ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (3)
```

Or you can do so by aligning on indices, which will assign only those elements with a matching index. See how the temporary data frame doesn't pull over elements for indices 4 and 5:

```
>>> df['C'] = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'D': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}).set_index('A')
   B  C
A      
1  7  4
2  8  5
3  9  6
```

In your case, you are trying to assign values based on the first method, which will fail if you have different lengths.

You want instead to align on the dates, which will require you to set index in `df1` to column `A`. To align on indices, you must also have the *same* index types in both data frames. Then you can directly attach the corresponding values from the index created by your `groupby`. Thus:

```
df1.set_index('A', inplace=True)
df1['D'] = df2.groupby('D')['E'].sum()
```